# Minor wording change in "Access review queues" privilege explanation

Tags: bug, review, privileges

I recently was awarded the "access review queues" privilege on a Stack Exchange site and I noticed that on [privileges list screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), the privilege is described as "Access First posts and Late answers review queues":

[image: access review queues privilege link on privileges link page]

This does not seem to have been updated since the First posts queue was split.

Comment: First posts is not there on meta, so this is another bug.